# how to implement Heron function recursive

Tags: recursion, square-root

The function is:

```
Xn+1 = 1/2 * (Xn + a/Xn)
```

The method should look like this:

```
hsqrt(a)
```

You give it a Number and it should calculate the root (until the number is1E-3). So basically i give the function a startvalue "Xn = 1" and from there it should calculate by recursion:

E.g.

```
1/2 * (1 + 3/1) -> the result is the new Xn
```

but if I make it call itself like this `hsqrt(1/2 * (Xn + 3/Xn)` a is getting the calculated value instead of `Xn` and I have no clue how to change it.

And the other question is how should be the condition to stop if the number gets 1E-3 long.

I'm not asking for a solution, just some hints.

Comment: You don't literally "make it call itself". You can have a function defined `hsqrt(a, x)` and have it compute `(x + a/x)/2`. This computes a refined square root of `a` given approximation `x`. It returns a value, say `x_new`. You then check how different x is from `x_new` (check `abs(x-x_new)` is small enough as desired). If it isn't small enough, set `x` to `x_new` and repeat. This would typically be done with a loop, not recursion.

Comment: The task says it should be recursive. And the method hsqrt(a) is given aswell